# Getting JavaFX to run via Browser for Simple HelloWorld app

Tags: java, javafx

I tried following various tutorials for getting a JavaFX hello world app running in a browser. I can't believe it's that hard, so I'm looking for any insight into what I may have done wrong. Some things I've tried and resolved (to rule out the obvious):

- Had to download 32-bit JRE for the browsers and ensure they were using that
- Thus using the latest JRE (7u21); running on Win 7 64-bit
- Checked Windows Control Panel -> Programs -> Java to verify the JRE being used
- Signed the JAR file
- Tried running from local file, found that drive letters weren't recognized, so moved to running via Tomcat 6
- Tried various changes to the codebase and url hrefs, but I believe those are correct.
- Tried in both IE 10 and Chrome

What I ended up with was that loading the .html (which references the jnlp using the JavaFX default javascript) would spin for a while then fail. If I try to load the .jnlp file directly, I get an exception:

```
ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
```

I verified that the jfxrt.jar is in the lib folder of the JRE that the browser is using.

Any insight/suggestions as to what I may be missing at this point? Seems like it must be something obvious/basic at this point, but I'm not seeing it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your Manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow-up, I went ahead and used javafxpackager. That produced a web page that would load the JavaFX application in Chrome. However, it still doesn't work in IE. I'm going to write that off as an IE but since it works in Chrome. What I did learn by looking at the results, though, is there are several things javafxpackager does, and the results of that are not exactly what's described in most of the manual tutorials/examples. Minor differences, but apparently they matter.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as you don't have the JavaFX starter classes in your JAR (usually done by the Ant script) and don't have the correct JavaFX Manifest entries.

It should not be needed to add the jfxrt.jar as a resource to your JNLP file and you shouldn't have to sign it.

Please show your Manifest file.

The Manifest file should contain at least the following JavaFX entries:

```
JavaFX-Version: 2.2
JavaFX-Application-Class: yourPackage.YourApplication
Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main
```

The JAR should contain the classes of the `com.javafx.main` package provided by the ant-javafx.jar (see /resources/classes in that Jar). The ant-javafx.jar is provided by the JDK.

Comment: I didn't do any explicit Manifest file, so I'd have only what's auto-generated. I can post, but it likely won't help. If the javafx packaging tools add to it, this falls into the case of things I'd like to understand and know what it's doing for me.

Comment: Actually if you are trying to run javafx in normal browser then we must follow up the Manifest file. More over you need to keep jfxrt.jar in your classpath. Alaso make sure that you are compiling from Netbeans using JavaFX project instead of only Java Project.

Comment: @privatejava No, if you're using the Main class I mentioned, you shouldn't have to add the jfxrt.jar to your classpath (manually), AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to mostly resolve my problem. I'm using Eclipse, not NetBeans, so doing a lot manually. The basic problem was that I had to include the jfxrt.jar as a resource in the jnlp file (and that jar also had to be signed).

My app now runs if I access the jnlp directly, though it still doesn't work via html page. I'll post an update if/when I figure that part out.

Comment: Hand editing jnlp files for JavaFX is not really recommended.  If you are using Eclipse for development, you are better off using [e(fx)clipse](http://www.efxclipse.org/).  You should also consider some additional tool support such as the [JavaFX ant tasks or JavaFX packager](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) or JavaFX Maven or Gradle plugins.

Comment: @user1676075 I don't think this is the way to go. See my answer.

Comment: I realize using the tools would be the easiest way to go. But I want to truly understand what's going on, which (to me) means doing these steps by hand, not having a tool hide any piece of it from me. Once I understand it, then I'm OK letting the tool do the work.